# A doubt in the stars and bars approach in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I want to find positive integral solutions to the equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3=6$$ Since the stars and bars method is for dividing identical objects into distinct boxes, it would count, say, $1+2+3$ as different from $2+1+3$ or $1+3+2$ or any other of the $3!=6$ permutations as different from each other right? (since what box it is put in is considered) But that doesn't seem to be the case, because the number of solutions we get from stars and bars here is $10$ which is not divisible by $3!$. Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why it should be divisible by $3!$?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg I thought that since by stars and bars all the 3! permutations for each combination would be counted as different, if we divide by it we could get the number of solutions for identical objects and identical boxes (instead of distinct boxes) But Parcly Taxel has pointed out an obvious flaw in doing so

Comment: What you can say is that the number of positive integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are all distinct is $3!$ times the number of solutions to  $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ where $0 <x_1<x_2<x_3$ (i.e. the number of partitions of $n$ into three distinct positive parts), which is also  $x_1+x_2+x_3=n-6$ where $0 \le x_1\le x_2\le x_3$ (i.e. the number of partitions of $n-6$ into up to three parts)

Answer (score 2):

There are some solutions which remain invariant under some or all permutations, e.g. $(2,2,2)$. Therefore the number of solutions to an $n$-variable equation obtained by stars and bars may not be divisible by $n!$, and this does not invalidate the method.

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake. Can you also tell me, then, how will we find what I was looking for? (ie, no of ways of distributing 10 identical objects in 3 identical boxes opposed to 3 distinct boxes

Comment: For 10 I can just make cases when the permutations are invariant but how can we generalise?

Comment: @l1mbo Identical objects into identical boxes is a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), a much harder problem.

Comment: @oh, thanks; I'd just wasted more than 30 minutes thinking about the problem, if only I had known better :(